# Git branch in the prompt

Tags: bash, rc

Could anyone explain why the branch name is not showing up on my (`bash`) prompt?
I am using ubuntu 16.10.  I tried to use the instructions from this [site](https://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac/).

```
# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

My `.bashrc` file is here: https://github.com/JeremieGauthier/.bashrc/blob/master/.bashrc

I also tried the following code but it didn't work either.

```
function color_my_prompt {
    local __user_and_host="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h"
    local __cur_location="\[\033[01;34m\]\w"
    local __git_branch_color="\[\033[31m\]"
    #local __git_branch="\`ruby -e \"print (%x{git branch 2> /dev/null}.grep(/^\*/).first || '').gsub(/^\* (.+)$/, '(\1) ')\"\`"
    local __git_branch='`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`'
    local __prompt_tail="\[\033[35m\]$"
    local __last_color="\[\033[00m\]"
    export PS1="$__user_and_host $__cur_location $__git_branch_color$__git_branch$__prompt_tail$__last_color "
}
color_my_prompt
```

Comment: Rather than `git branch` (which is a porcelain command), you should use `get rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get the branch name.  And if you stop discarding the error message you may see that perhaps you are not in a git working directory, so `parse_git_branch` generates no output.

Answer (score 2):

At installation `git` comes with a [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) that a bash function `__git_ps1` to update the prompt.

The function is simple and add the current branch when you cd inside a git repo directory.

Just add a call to this function or another one available in your `ps1` and make sure your `.bashrc` or your `.bash_profile` load the `bash_completion` directory.

If your version of git doesn't include the `git_prompt.sh` script, manually download it and follow the instructions it provide.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), futureproof command line prompt support (in `contrib/`).

You can take inspiration from their patch, to display the name of the branch reliably based on HEAD (`get rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`), which is now compited as:

```bash
case "$ref_format" in
files)
    if ! __git_eread "$g/HEAD" head; then
        return $exit
    fi

    if [[ $head == "ref: "* ]]; then
        head="${head#ref: }"
    else
        head=""
    fi
    ;;
*)
    head="$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
    ;;
esac
```

See [commit fc134b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc134b41ce2ee7b2a98a988db6eeb109e11a2831) (04 Jan 2024) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
See [commit 4081d45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4081d45d7f01ff50853ef66fb2579f0d64f13bb9) (08 Jan 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9ea8145](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ea8145387a942a55386a197bfc870dbbb530ede), 19 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`git-prompt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc134b41ce2ee7b2a98a988db6eeb109e11a2831): stop manually parsing HEAD with unknown ref formats
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> We're manually parsing the HEAD reference in `git-prompt` to figure out whether it is a symbolic or direct reference.
> This makes it intimately tied to the on-disk format we use to store references and will stop working once we gain additional reference backends in the Git project.
>
> Ideally, we would refactor the code to exclusively use plumbing tools to read refs such that we do not have to care about the on-disk format at all.
> Unfortunately though, spawning processes can be quite expensive on some systems like Windows.
> As the Git prompt logic may be executed quite frequently we try very hard to spawn as few processes as possible.
> This refactoring is thus out of question for now.
>
> Instead, condition the logic on the repository's ref format: if the repo uses the the "files" backend we can continue to use the old logic and read the respective files from disk directly.
> If it's anything else, then we use git-symbolic-ref(1) to read the value of HEAD.
>
> This change makes the Git prompt compatible with the upcoming "reftable" format.